# references on creating web server in php

Tags: php, webserver, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [http server in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937457/http-server-in-php)

I want to work in web server in php . Where I can get better resources??? I specially want to know how php create connection with client and transfer data.I am using localhost .So what i have to do to find the server from different client(written in java or other platform).

Comment: You already asked this on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937457/http-server-in-php