# HTTP server written on php

Tags: php, http, console

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP web server in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131679/php-web-server-in-php)
>   [http server in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937457/http-server-in-php)

I want to use HTTP server written on PHP instead of Apache. Who knows solutions? Best is one php file.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea, and I think it's not even feasible.

Comment: @hexa: Why wouldn't that be feasible?

Comment: Google knows. First link will give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It was done once for some kind of a proof of concept we did, as PHP is faster to develop in than, say CPP. but in no way it is a solution for a production environment.
Others have done so too http://nanoweb.si.kz/ is one for example.